# JQuery find rows with "not" attribute

Tags: jquery, html

I know I can find rows with this JQuery...

```
$("[attr1][attr2]")....
```

This will find rows with with both attr1 and attr2.

But how can I find rows that has attr1, but NOT attr2?

Is there a...

```
$("[attr1]![attr2]")....
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [not()](http://api.jquery.com/not/):

```
$("[attr1]").not("[attr2]")
```

Comment: I just love JQuery ... and thanks for taking time to help me out. Never thought of using "not".